# i am trying to send request to https://www.google.com and get a responce. I am using asyncTask but getting the following exception

Tags: android

```
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4607)
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:835)
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:292)
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6303)
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3547)
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3405)
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3380)
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768):     at com.example.internet.MainActivity$RequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:150)
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768):     at com.example.internet.MainActivity$RequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-17 11:01:44.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1768):     ... 5 more
12-17 11:01:44.857: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1768): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: you cant update your `UI` in `doInBackground()`,you cant set text to TextView in `doInBackground()`.

Comment: without looking into the code, how can we show you exact issue?

Comment: please put your code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the cause.

`Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

UI cant be updated from `doInBackground`

You should provide the code as well , specifically for the relevant part.

Here is an example  of an approach that can be used

```
private class SaveProfile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
    //---------- so your stuff here.... non ui related

    Log.v("response from saving",response);

    if(response.equals("1")){

        return true;                
    }else{

        return false;
    }
}

protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

     if(result) {

                  //------ UPDATE UI HERE
         Toast.makeText(ProfileCompanyActivity.this, "profile saved", 2500).show();
     }else{
         Toast.makeText(ProfileCompanyActivity.this, "an error occured", 2500).show();
     }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must Understand the Concept of AsynTask in android...

1) you cannot update or change your UI element in backGround thread i.e doInBackGround()

2) use onPreExcecute() or onPostExcecute() to change or update your UI element

And to be Sure you are accessing UI element into doInBackGround

[Check out this Example to Understant how the Methods work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example/18827536#18827536)

Hope this could help....

Comment: thanks all i was trying to update a edit text from doInBackGround. now i got it.

Comment: @user3109807 Pleasure...love to help